# Probability Problem of 2i offensive-defensive players

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Question: A football team consists of 20 offensive and 20 defensive players. The players are to be paired in groups of 2 for the purpose of determining roommates. What is the probability that there are 2i offensive–defensive roommate pairs, i = 1,2,...,10?**

20 Offensive (O), 20 Defensive (D) ==> 40 people total and 20 pairs

The question asks for the probability of 2i OD pairs. If we have 2i OD pairs, then we have (20−2i) OO and DD pairs. So I think the solution will be of form:

$\frac{(\mbox{total OD pair combinations})  \cdot (\mbox{total OO Comb)(total DD comb})}{\mbox{total unordered pair combinations}  }$

Therefore, the answer will be:

$\cfrac{\binom{20}{2i}^2(2i)! \left[ \cfrac{(20-2i)!}{2^{10-i}(10-i)!} \right]^2}  {\cfrac{40!}{2^{20}20! }}   i=0,1,...,10$

My question is, **when i=10**, the numerator should be logically $(20!)$
But here the second part of the numerator becomes $\cfrac{0}{0}$. So I can't proceed further.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use that $0!=1$